# ffmpeg - generate video with more then 2 images and 2 audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have `n` images (2 < images < n) and 2 audio files
I generate a video like below and it works:

```
$ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -framerate 1/10 \
        -i '*.jpg' -i "concat:Q.mp3|R.mp3" -shortest \
        -strict experimental -f mp4 -vcodec mpeg4    \
        -b 1200k -s 848x480 out.mp4
```

But what I want to do is:

- looping on the first image till the end of the first audio track
- then slide on rest of pics till the end of the second audio

Any help will be welcomed.
Rgds
Tvart

Comment: Images? or Videos? Also this seems to be pretty elaborate, are you sure that you don't want to use a full fledged GUI editor like pitivi or something?

Comment: I need to generate videos from images and audio files.
The problem is that I have to do that programatically ( as I have to use this template / way to generate more than 100 videos. )

Comment: And each time I know that the first image should be looped till the end of my first audio file, then  iterate on the rest of images with the framerate = (nb_images-1)/duration_of_second_audio_file

Comment: I see, I've never used ffmpeg to generate videos from images myself, but maybe instead of generating one video from 2 images and 2 audio files, you should generate a video from 1 image and 1 audio file twice, then merge them?

Comment: You could probably automate it pretty nicely with a bash script.